# How can I run a stored procedure that has no return values from C# with my db context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am using the following code to run a stored procedure:

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();
var a = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("dbo.getQuestionUIdsByTopicId @TopicId",
           new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "TopicId", Value = testTopicId });
```

This works good but now I will have a stored procedure that does not return any data other than a return code.

How can I execute a stored procedure with a parameter using my context **db.Database** and have the stored procedure return only a return code? If someone could give an example of a 3-4 line SP and how it returns a return code that would also be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ExecuteSqlCommand` to send non-query commands to the database.

```
int result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sproc...");
```

See [this link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx) for more info.